# How can I view the stdout buffer before flushing it?

Tags: c, printf, buffer, stdout, flush

Is it possible to view what is in my `stdout` buffer prior to flushing it? And if so, how?

For example, I'm debugging the following code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    printf("%d ", i);
}
printf("\n"); // Break point on this line
```

If I stop at the last line with my debugger, I want to view that buffer, which should contain `"0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 "`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You normally cannot, but if you use [`setvbuf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setbuf.3.html) you can override the private buffer used by libc with one created by you. Doing this before those `printf()` calls should make the data end up in your buffer before being flushed.

```
char mybuffer[BUFSIZ]; // BUFSIZ is defined in <stdio.h>
setvbuf(stdout, mybuffer, _IOLBF, BUFSIZ);
```

In any case, what you will find inside the buffer is definitely *not* something that is documented, so the contents of the buffer might not be what you expect. Doing some tests on my own for example, I found that glibc does not seem to like small buffer sizes and ignores the user buffer sometimes (you should be ok with `BUFSIZ` though).